# odbc_execute with parameters not working (empty warning)

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc

I'm trying to execute a simple select-query on a MS-Access Database.
Of course i want to prevent SQL-injections, so i want to use a prepared statement with parameters

```
$conn = odbc_connect("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=/path/to/mdb/file.mdb", "ADODB.Connection", "password", SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);
$res = odbc_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE holdingnumber = ?");
odbc_execute($res, array( 20000 ));
$row = odbc_fetch_array($res);
print_r($row);
```

when i try that, i get an empty warning:

```
Warning: odbc_execute(): in D:\xampp\htdocs\ZEOnline\test.php on line 5
```

but when i do it without parameters (replacing the '?' with 20000 and removing the array from odbc_execute), it works.

Does anyone know why this isn't working or is there any other way to properly escape strings for odbc?

PHP version is 5.4.4, MS Access Driver should be the latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for the error long ago. I saw somebody upvoting this so I'm posting this now:

MS Access does simply not support prepared statements!

It's a bit confusing because PHP actually lets you use the odbc_prepare() call as long as there are no actual parameters and the error message says nothing relevant.

But it's just not possible to do prepared statements with a MS ACCESS database.